# Play audio of flash video while screen is off?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, adobe-flash

I want to listen to the audio portion of flash on my Droid preferably with the screen off.  Sites like InfoQ.com have great interviews in flash that I want to just listen to.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to keep my phone on and the screen off to save power before. I have made use of this app and it works well for me.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.japp.blackscreen

This app needs the ability to display over other apps, but it has saved me a lot of battery. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

This may be a silly thing to say, but have you tried loading a site with flash, and letting it play? I would have thought it would just continue even if the screen goes blank.

If it does stop when the screen goes blank, can you download it and play it using one of the audio players that supports .flv and has the option to continue playing in the backgound? Is there an app that can play .flv?

Regarding playing non-MP4 or H.264:

- Chinese app called [Wuzhenhua Player](http://mobiputing.com/2010/03/media-player-for-android-that-can-handle-wmv-flv-xvid-etc/)
- [RockPlayerBase](http://mobiputing.com/2010/06/rockplayerbase-the-best-media-player-for-android-divx-xvid-wmv-support/)
- [CorePlayer](http://coreplayer.com/), but doesn't seem to support Android (it's got a mobile version :/)
- [DroidACIR](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.leadapps.android.radio.acir) says it supports .flv-based audio streams
- [Another flv player](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.ohisamallc.Anflv)

Here's a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431351/how-do-i-pause-flash-content-in-an-android-webview-when-my-activity-isnt-visible) about having trouble *stopping* flash when leaving the browser.

HTH

Comment: Yes I have tried.  As soon as the screen blanks while I just listen at my desk (to save battery life) the audio stops.  Example presentation I want to listen to while driving preferably:  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/08/19.html

Comment: @Brian Do you charge your phone while driving? If so you could switch on the "Stay awake: phone will never sleep while charging" option under the Development settings to stop the screen turning off.