# YouTube - How can i play my youtube playlist in my android phone even my screen automatically goes to sleep mode?

Tags: youtube

In my samsung galaxy s4, i am playing my youtube playlists like 10 or 20 musics and when i switch off the screen then the music stops.

How can i play forever the music even the screen is on or off?

For example:

1) i am in Gym

2) i open the youtube music playlist and let it play by switching off my screen and head phone is on

3) now when i am doing my workout the music is stoopped

How can i keep it play forever unless i manually close it.

Comment: Don't think it's currently possible with YouTube: [How to play a YouTube clip in background/minimised?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3079)

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/9754/9531

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible but it should be soon. According to [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/10/22/apk-teardown-youtube-5-2-27-hallelujah-background-audio-is-finally-coming-to-youtube-for-android/) background audio is coming in a future release of the YouTube app.