# How to play youtube in the background in android?

Tags: music, youtube

I have been using PVSTAR+ app which plaeyed youtube in the background and I could listen to youtube while its closed.

Youtube recently updated it's API so PVSTAR+ doesnt work anymore.
it's also have been deleted from the store so I wont get any updates.

Is there an app that play youtube in the background and works now?
And I dont want to use AudioPocket-it can't search youtube.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this post http://android.stackexchange.com/a/90288/81850