# Sound from VLC video after locking screen

Tags: vlc

So I'm watching a video talk in VLC on my Samsung I9305 rooted stock 4.4.4 with Xposed Framework, and I want to lock the screen and put the phone in my pocket, but still continue listening to the audio of the talk. Is it possible to do this with VLC, or do I have to switch to another media player?

Comment: Definitely possible but depends upon on what length you would go to keep VLC as the choice of player here. Example, you can put the brightness to `0` and cover the screen with an overlay in blocking mode. Also, disable all the navigational hardware buttons too when VLC is active. It can be done easily but do you want this mess?

Comment: @ Firelord It turns out this is actually a native function of VLC for Android! It's very easy, I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out this is actually a native function of VLC 1.7.4 (and probably previous versions too) for Android.

1. Click the three horizontal lines in the top left corner (on the file selection screen, not while a video is playing).
2. Click on "Preferences".
3. Tick the "Play videos in background" box.
4. Play a video.
5. Lock the screen.
6. Keep listening to the audio from that video!

Comment: It seems you can't combine Picture-in-picture (aka Popup player) with the play in background, as for example Yoube Vanced does.
It would be nice to be able to play the video in the popup player + keep the audio playing when locking the screen.

Answer (score 3):

i have Huawei mate 9 and i have found one resolution which is Phone Battery is locking VLC player to run in back ground see attached screenshots which we have to enable.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those options are specific to Huawei phones, so while they might be helpful to other Huawei customers, they won't help with the Samsung phone the question is about.

Comment: @DanHulme Interestingly, shortly before this answer was posted, I switched to a Huawei Mate device. So this answer was almost like an update for my new device. Just funny.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Samsung Note 8, even with "Play videos in background" setting turned on. In the latest version of VLC (v3.3.4), the "Play videos in the background" option is a little different, it's actually "Background/PiP mode" with 3 options:

- Stop
- Play videos in background
- Play videos in Piciture-in-picture mode

The issue for me was the power saving setting, similar to THE PATHAN's answer for their Huawei Mate 9.

Here's how to fix it on a Samsung:

- Open Settings
- Open Apps
- Find and open VLC
- Click "Battery"
- Toggle "Allow background activity" to on

Without this setting, audio playback will be stopped about 30 seconds after locking the phone regardless of the "Background/PiP mode". However, with "Allow background activity" turned on, audio playback will continue even with the "Background/PiP mode" set to "Stop".

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work for you? [YouTube player](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/90288/143025)
That is a YouTube player that plays after the screen is locked.

Comment: I already have this function for Youtube. I'm looking for the same function with VLC or another video player.