# Playing offline YouTube videos with screen locked

Tags: youtube

I am using OnePlus Two and I want to play the *offline videos* from YouTube in the locked screen.

The solution mentioned in the below link does not work:
[Lock screen while playing YouTube video](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/90265/)

Is there any way that it can be done?

Comment: what did not worked? Can you be more specific?

Comment: In the answer, it mentions that the videos can be opened via MX player. But I was not able to open.
Is there any steps missing that I should have followed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SnapTube](http://www.snaptubeapp.com/). It let's you download videos (or just the audio) from a number of sources, including Youtube. If you download only the audio, you can just use any standard audio player (or the built-in one) to listen to it with the screen off.

Disclaimer: not sure how this fits with Youtube terms of service, you may want to investigate that before using it on Youtube.