# Turn off screen but still let video and streams running

Tags: screen

Sometimes, I want to listen to streams or videos while I'm on the go, but I can't put my phone in my pocket because that would press buttons on the display. Is there any way to turn the screen off and still let the stream/video running like it does with music players?

Comment: If anybody else stumbles upon this: firefox on android does that for youtube and for local videos, but to open a local video I haven't found a better way yet than to paste `file://<path>`in the url box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Download [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad)
- Play YouTube/Sdcard video using MX Player.
- Press Menu button (or the 3 dot icon), and then select Play
- Make sure "Background Play" is checked
- Now, you can press Home Button and listen in lock screen.

**There is also a shortcut for enabling Background Play, which is tapping and holding the Play button, instead of just tapping it to play a video**

*Update:*

> **Only For Rooted**:
> You can install [Xposed Modules Installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) and use Repository called [Youtube Background Play](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.youtubebackgroundplayback)

- Copied from my own answer on [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/105516/81850)

**Update #2**

If you are open to installing mod [YouTube Vanced](https://vancedapp.com/) is the easiest way for getting background play feature and it works well for non-rooted Android too.