# How to watch Youtube with screen off on any Android without a Youtube Premium subscription

Tags: youtube

How can I listen to Youtube with my screen off without a Youtube Premium subscription

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play a YouTube clip in background/minimised?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-to-play-a-youtube-clip-in-background-minimised)

Comment: @firelord - Although your linked question addresses both aspects, there are apps that play youtube with screen off but not minimized (while using other apps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is to use [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=fr).
Once installed, install the extension [Video Background Play Fix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-background-play-fix/)

Go on youtube.com and enjoy your best video/podcast/music screen off.

You also can add [ublock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/?src=search) to Firefox to block any advertisement as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution, 
if you want to listen YouTube song even when your android phone is locked. To do that you have to use chrome browser in android phone. Open YouTube in chrome browser and request as Desktop Site and search for the song which you want to listen then minimise it. The song will be paused then, from the notification you can tap on the play(▶). By doing this you will be able to listen YouTube videos in your phone even if it is locked.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can download: YouTube Vanced. I am using this app myself and it works like a charm. You can also turn off the screen and still hear the music playing.

Answer (score 0):

[OGYoutube](https://ogyoutube.en.uptodown.com/android/download) can play with screen off.

But oddly it cannot play while minimized, which means you can only listen when not using the phone with other apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think [HBTube](https://hbtube.online/#eluid39a8eda2) is the best answer for your case at the moment. You can see my question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228725/how-to-download-video-from-youtube-framatube-media-ccc-or-mp3-from-soundcloud).

After few days used it, I want to share it to everyone. It allow to **download video from multi-channel like Youtube, FramaTube, Media CCC or audio from SoundCloud**.

You can do other tasks while watching videos on Youtube, learning on Media CCC or join conferences on Media CCC. Even it allows **play music with screen off**.

I hope this will solve your issue.

Best regards,
Lee

Comment: What is your affiliation with this app? You seem to have been promoting this app in both question and answers. Promotion is acceptable only when affiliation with the product is fully disclosed wherever the product is mentioned, and when it indeed answers the question.

Comment: Sorry mate, I'm Magento Developer. You can see my profile here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/75587/bachlee89 . I don't promote this app. I'm just want to share everything I think it's useful for every one. I do not receive any remuneration from this application.

Comment: Seems like a nice option, but I won't use a small app that isn't opensource without knowing a bit about who make it and how.