# How to download video from Youtube, FramaTube, Media CCC or mp3 from SoundCloud?

Tags: lock-screens, youtube, background-process, video-streaming, video-conference

I'm using Mi 5, I want to **download hot trend videos from Youtube, FramaTube** or video conferences from Mediaccc and then make the tiktok video for fun. How to reach this?
Also, sometimes I want to **listen Youtube music or offline video while screen off**. I found some answers but it is not working. Anyone can suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
[HBTube](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hb.tube.us). It allows to play Youtube background, download video, audio from multi platforms. No Ads when watching videos. You can visit [HBTube Online](http://hbtube.online) to see more detail.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello. Are you affiliated with this app? If so, please disclose the affiliation.

Comment: Thanks you. Just tried this app. Exactly which I want to find. Very good!