# How to play YouTube in browser while screen is off?

Tags: youtube

I'd prefer not to have to install some other weird apps or fiddle too much. (In particular I *don't* want to use NewPipe, Vanced.)

If it matters, I use

- Bloket browser (I'm willing to try other browsers but I must be able to block ads too).
- moto g(7) plus
- Android version 10

Comment: The duplicate also mentions [Firefox](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/81067/44325), [Brave](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/196367/44325) and [Chrome](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/185013/44325) browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) browser.

Install [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/ublock-origin/) for adblocking.

In Firefox go to ⋮ (Settings) > Turn on "Desktop site".