# AirPlay like app for the Video-out on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, video-out

I am trying to get the video out on the Galaxy Nexus to do something other than mirroring. In a perfect world I want to do something similiar to the iPhone's AirPlay, but instead of streaming the video to an AppleTV it just pushes the video to the video out accessed by the MHL cable. I would be alright with mirroring if I could lock the phone and it would still play video through the video-out, but to my knowledge that hasn't been accomplished pointing to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/play-audio-of-flash-video-while-screen-is-off) post and this [post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1331615&page=1) over at XDA Developers.

I know Android has the capabilities because of Motorola's webtop software but I'm wondering if there is a hardware issue involved too because if it's solely hardware there no reason why there couldn't be a viable solution to my problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want AirPlay functionality or display content using a cable?

Comment: I'm saying I would like either solution. I was using AirPlay as an example of what I was looking for.

Comment: What about [Skifta](http://www.skifta.com/).

Comment: I don't exactly know how Airplay works, but is [UPnPlay](https://market.android.com/details?id=cx.hoohol.silanoid) what you are looking for?

Comment: For AirPlay style solutions, take a look at [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) (this is the proper, standard way to do this as supported by many newer TVs, consoles, media streamers, etc) rather than the Apple only AirPlay thing, see this previous question: [Can I get DLNA on my Droid?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/can-i-get-dlna-on-my-droid) and other questions under the [DLNA tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dlna)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option [Skifta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skifta.android.app&hl=en). It uses DLNA and worked with my media center extenders as well as other Windows 7 computers.

Comment: The link is dead. An update is required here.